# Tapping 2 buttons simultaneously on UIAlertView freezes app

Tags: ios, uialertview, freeze

I have this bug: if I tap both buttons simultaneously on an `UIAlertView` the `UIAlertView` delegate will not be called, and the whole screen freezes (nothing is tappable, even though the alert view is dismissed).

Has anyone seen this bug before? Is there a way to restrict `UIAlertView` tapping to only one button?

```
- (IBAction)logoutAction:(id)sender {
        self.logoutAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout"
                                                              message:@"Are you sure you want to logout?"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [self.logoutAlertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if ([alertView isEqual:self.logoutAlertView]) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            NSLog(@"cancelled logout");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"user will logout");
            [self performLogout];
        }
        self.logoutAlertView.delegate = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of iOS?

Comment: iOs 8.1 is the complete version , using latest XCode

Comment: And the alertview delegate is properly retained?

Comment: Yes, (I am using ARC). When only 1 button is tapped there is no problem.

Comment: Try moving the code `self.logoutAlertView.delegate = nil` to the top of the delegate method. Perhaps calling `[self performLogout]` is causing an interrupt and allowing the other delegate method to be called. I updated my answer as an example.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. Did you ever find a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to tap multiple buttons on a UIAlertView and the delegate methods get called for each tap. However, this should not "freeze" your app. Step through your code to find the issue.

To prevent multiple events from being handled, set the UIAlertView's delegate property to nil after processing the first one:

```
- (void)showAlert {
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
  [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   // Avoid further delegate calls
   alertView.delegate = nil;

   // Do something
   if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
     // User cancelled, do something
   } else {
     // User tapped OK, do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps be more specific because I tested this before I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Use UIAlertController on iOS 8:

```
if ([UIAlertController class])
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Logout" message:@"Are you sure you want to logout?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
    {
        NSLog(@"cancelled logout");
    }]];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
    {
        NSLog(@"user will logout");
        [self performLogout];
    }]];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    self.logoutAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout"
                                                      message:@"Are you sure you want to logout?"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [self.logoutAlertView show];
}
```

Comment: Won't work... it displays an alert over the controller, at that point my controller is not centered in the screen (hamburger menu with slide out active) so the alert will be way off center, or if I use the background controller that contains the menu it won't show because the alert will be hidden behind the top most controller

Comment: @user1028028 Then you should get your root controller, not background controller, in my case it was rootViewCotroller = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows lastObject] rootViewController]

Comment: It wouldn't work, it will be centered but unlike AlertView that would be an alert that is displayed behind the other view controllers